# Using Bootstrap popover without pulling in entire CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm interested in using the impressive Bootstrap popover jquery plugin, but don't want to pull-in the entire massive bootstrap.css, since it run over my existing style sheets.

I've tried to cherry-pick the tooltip-only components out of the CSS, but failed.  Any ideas as to the best way to go about this?

Comment: Did you try the custom export?

Comment: I did, but it segments CSS by "headings, code, labels, badges" etc.  So I couldn't produce a custom CSS using the customize feature as far as I could determine.

Comment: @juwiley Aside from the popover css, you need to also include the tooltip option on the custom download screen.

Comment: Ahh, missed that step 1 is select CSS (I saw 'JS Components').  If you put that as answer ill mark it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to select two check boxes on the custom download page.  Select the appropriate CSS JS Component in step one and then select the corresponding jQuery plugin in step 2.

See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/download.html